# Getting getting cURL error 6 when doing authentication using Socialite in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, curl, laravel-socialite

I'm using Socialite package in Laravel to do auth. I've uploaded the app to my hosting for so long time and auth always went success. but lately, it runs into some cURL error basically saying `GuzzleHttp \ Exception \ ConnectException cURL error 6: getaddrinfo() thread failed to start (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)`. I have no idea why this is happening. I've read some articles and nothing can solve my problem. Does anyone have an idea how to solve this problem?. Thank you.

Here's my code

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;
use App\User;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Laravel\Socialite\Facades\Socialite;
class AuthController extends Controller
{
    public function redirectToProvider($provider)
    {
        return Socialite::driver($provider)->redirect();
    }
    /**
     * Obtain the user information from provider.  Check if the user already exists in our
     * database by looking up their provider_id in the database.
     * If the user exists, log them in. Otherwise, create a new user then log them in. After that
     * redirect them to the authenticated users homepage.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function handleProviderCallback($provider)
    {
        $user = Socialite::driver($provider)->user();
        $authUser = $this->findOrCreateUser($user, $provider);
        Auth::login($authUser, true);
        return redirect('/');
    }
    /**
     * If a user has registered before using social auth, return the user
     * else, create a new user object.
     * @param  $user Socialite user object
     * @param $provider Social auth provider
     * @return  User
     */
    public function findOrCreateUser($user, $provider)
    {
        $authUser = User::where('provider_id', $user->id)->first();
        if ($authUser) {
            return $authUser;
        }
        else{
            $data = User::create([
                'name'     => $user->name,
                'email'    => !empty($user->email)? $user->email : '' ,
                'provider' => $provider,
                'provider_id' => $user->id
            ]);
            return $data;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: cURL error 6 means `Couldn't resolve host. The given remote host was not resolved.` This means that libcurl could not convert a hostname (presumably of an authentication server. I don't know `Socialite`) to an IP address. This implies one of the following: 1.) The server that Socialite is telling libcurl to connect it is no longer correct; or 2.) There's a problem with the DNS configuration on the server where your PHP code is running. or 3.) (unlikely) there could be a problem with your /etc/hosts file.

Comment: Related https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/issues/1901